# Can an upperbound constraint on the squared Frobenius norm of a matrix be expressed as a linear matrix inequality?

Tags: trace, linear-matrix-inequality, matrix-norms

Is it possible to express an inequality constraint on the squared Frobenius norm of a matrix $X$:

$$\|X\|_F^2 = \mathop{tr}( X^T X ) \le t$$

as a linear matrix inequality?

I want to say that it's:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} I & X \\ X^T  & tI\end{array}\right] \succcurlyeq  0$$

but I've lost confidence that this is correct since the Schur complement would be $tI - X^TX \succcurlyeq 0 $ and I can't figure how the trace gets in there.

Comment: Does your round greater equal sign stand for determinant? If so than what you wrote does not work for 2 by 2 matrices (unless I made a computation error somewhere).

Comment: I intended $M \succcurlyeq 0$ to mean $M$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Positive semidefinite is equivalent to eigenvalues greater equal zero. I think that doesn't even work for 1 by 1 matrices.

Comment: what doesn't work for 1by1? The Schur complement in that case says $t - x^2  \succcurlyeq 0$ or $c (t -x^2) c \ge 0,\ \forall c$ which simply means $(t -x^2)\ge 0$ which in this case is the same as $\mathop{tr}(x^2) = x^2 \le t$.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a compacter and more elegant way, but one way you can represent it as LMI's is by using intermediate values for each diagonal term of $X^\top X$. These can be calculated using

$$
Y_i = X\,e_i
$$

with $e_i$ a vector with the $i$th element equal to one and the rest zeros (so $Y_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$), such that $Y_i^\top Y_i$ is the $i$th diagonal term of $X^\top X$. Then using the Schur complement you can write for every diagonal term an LMI for $Y_i^\top Y_i \leq \alpha_i$, namely

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & Y_i \\ Y_i^\top & \alpha_i
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,
$$

with $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Now a bound for $\|X\|_F^2$ can be found by summing all $\alpha_i$, which should be smaller or equal to $t$

$$
\sum \alpha_i \leq t,
$$

which is also a linear inequality.

---

By using an intermediate LMI for $X^\top X$ you might also be able to write $X^\top X \preceq M$, with $M = M^\top$, as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & X \\ X^\top & M
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
$$

An upper bound for $\|X\|_F^2$ would then be $\text{Tr}(M)$, so adding the linear inequality $\text{Tr}(M) \leq t$ would make this system of LMI's equivalent to your problem. To show that $X^\top X \preceq M$ also implies that $\text{Tr}(X^\top X) \leq \text{Tr}(M)$ you can use that the [trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of all its eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Eigenvalue_relationships). Namely $X^\top X \preceq M$ is equivalent to $M - X^\top X \succeq 0$, thus $M - X^\top X$ can only have non-negative eigenvalues and therefore $\text{Tr}(M - X^\top X)$ is the sum of these non-negative eigenvalues, which is also non-negative. The trace inequality $\text{Tr}(X^\top X) \leq \text{Tr}(M)$ is equivalent to $\text{Tr}(M - X^\top X) \geq 0$ and in the previous sentence it was shown that it holds when $X^\top X \preceq M$, thus $\text{Tr}(X^\top X) \leq \text{Tr}(M)$ should hold in that case as well.

It can be noted that $M$ might add more degrees of freedom than all $\alpha_i$ so might or might not be an attractive alternative of writing the problem as LMI's.